# Access GitLab running in a docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ee

I'm trying to set up **GitLab as a docker container** in an internal server. Let's assume the server's IP is `10.10.10.10`. Below is my docker-compose file that I use to bring up the container. I'm unable to access the http url via `localhost:4080` (from a browser within the server) OR via the IP `10.10.10.10:4080`. I'd like to understand what I'm missing here.

```
version: '2'

services:

  gitlab:
    image: gitlab-ee-img:12.0.9-ee.0
    container_name: gitlab
    restart: always
    hostname: 'localhost:4080'
    # environment:
    #   GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
    #     # Add any other gitlab.rb configuration here, each on its own line
    #     # external_url 'https://gitlab.example.com'
    #     external_url 'http://127.0.0.1:4080'
    ports:
      - '4080:80'
      - '4443:443'
      - '4022:22'
    volumes:
      - '/data/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
      - '/data/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - '/data/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
```

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure about if there's something else not working there but I'm fairly sure that the `hostname: 'localhost:4080'` block is not correct. It should be just the hostname without a port. Try to comment out that line and try without defining a hostname at all for testing.

src: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#domainname-hostname-ipc-mac_address-privileged-read_only-shm_size-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I happened to dig around a bit in the gitlab forums and found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone hitting this SO question:

The answer is to NOT map a custom port on to 80 in docker. Instead, this will work:

```
version: '2'

services:

  gitlab:
    image: gitlab-ee-img:12.0.9-ee.0
    container_name: gitlab
    restart: always
    hostname: '10.10.10.10'
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        # Add any other gitlab.rb configuration here, each on its own line
        # external_url 'https://gitlab.example.com'
        external_url 'http://10.10.10.10:4080'
        gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 4022
    ports:
      - '4080:4080'
      - '4443:443'
      - '4022:22'
    volumes:
      - '/data/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
      - '/data/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - '/data/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
```

The reason is explained in [this thread](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/change-all-project-urls-to-use-ip-address/18544) - Specifically, [this answer](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/change-all-project-urls-to-use-ip-address/18544/9?u=blueren)

To summarize here (quoting the original answer),

> The default port of gitlab is 80, but when you use the external_url
>   clause, gitlab changes the ngnix port to which it is going to listen
>   or resolve, it is not just an alias.
>
> If you inside the container executes the command curl
>   http://localhost, after having placed external_url
>   http://10.10.10.10:4080, it will not answer for port 80, you can try
>   with the command curl http://10.10.10.10:4080